# Can I detect a ghost hidden soldier in multiplayer

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I have noticed when playing MP that sometimes I cant move to a specific position.
All there is is the yellow circle and cover does not trigger (as it does when you select a certain point to move your soldier).

My question are:

1. If an enemy in ghost is standing in a certain position, how does that reflect when I want to move to that same spot?
2. And do scanners show up ghosted soldier?

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

My answer only about first point: 
When enemy standing in certain position, you can't move your soldier to that position and yellow border show this. So, watching yellow border is common tactics to detect ghost soldiers.